# Laravel globally installs 4.1.1 instead of 8.0.1

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to install laravel 8 globally but it is installing version 4.1.1 every time. I use this code:

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

[image]

Then i check version by writing this:

```
laravel -V
```

[image]

How can i install the latest version?

Note: it only happens when i install it globally

Comment: Please share more details - what makes you think that `laravel/installer` has any later version than v4.1.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `composer global require laravel/installer` it installs the **Laravel Installer** globally. The installers latest release is 4.1.1 - see [Github releases](https://github.com/laravel/installer/releases)

To create a new Laravel 8 project you need to run

```
$ laravel new example-app
```

after you installed the installer. Find these steps in the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#the-laravel-installer).

#### Determine the version

**Option 1**

Run `php artisan --version` in your folder where you installed your project.

**Option 2**

After you created your project you can go into the folder where you installed it, f. ex. `example-app`, and chech the file `composer.json`.

There you can find a `require` section with the packages `laravel/framework` telling you the correct version.

```json
{
    // ... other stuff

    "require": {
        // ... other packages
        "laravel/framework": "^8.12",

    }
}
```

You probably need to familiarize yourself with [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) and how package management works.

Comment: How do i check its version afterwards?

Comment: ```php artisan --version```

Comment: Got it. Thanks guys :)

Comment: @GonrasKarols if I use this command today `laravel new example-app` I think it will create laravel 9. How to install Laravel 8?

Comment: You can try to `composer create-project laravel/laravel my-project 8.0.*`